# Why is it possible to have properties named the same as their return types?

Tags: c#

In C#, why is it possible to do this

```
public Int32 Int32 { get; set; }
```

but not this

```
public int int { get; set; }
```

I should have been more clean in my question, is there any reason why a return type of a property can have the same name as the property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables may not named the same as language keywords in C#.  `int` is a keyword; `Int32` is a type.

Note that the type and the property name are not actually the same; their fully-qualified names are different.  One is `System.Int32`, and the other is `YourClass.Int32`.

If you **really** want to name your property "int" (don't do this), you can use the verbatim operator:

```
public int @int { get; set; }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The prefix "@" enables the use of
>   keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other
>   programming languages. The character @
>   is not actually part of the
>   identifier, so the identifier might be
>   seen in other languages as a normal
>   identifier, without the prefix. An
>   identifier with an @ prefix is called
>   a verbatim identifier. **Use of the @
>   prefix for identifiers that are not
>   keywords is permitted, but strongly
>   discouraged as a matter of style.**

Comment: Why is it possible to have the property named the same as the return type though?

Comment: @Vince: why should it not be possible?  It's not great style, IMO, but there's nothing inherently **wrong** with it.

Comment: @Vince: I think I understand your confusion.  I added this to my answer: "Note that the type and the property name are not actually the same; their fully-qualified names are different.  One is `System.Int32`, and the other is `YourClass.Int32`."

Comment: Awesome Michael, thats what I was looking for :-)

Comment: "It's not great style" -- but it's not inherently poor style and shouldn't be discouraged for the sake of it.  Often, a type name will happen to be a good name for a property (at least for richer types than Int32).  E.g. consider the WPF Style property: would it have been better if they'd tried to find a synonym or prefix so as to avoid having the same name as the Style class?  I'd say choose a good property name and a good type name, and if they happen to be the same, go for it!

Comment: @itowlson: It can be confusing to read code that uses the same name for a partially-qualified type and a variable, especially if you didn't write the code.  Anything that impedes readability should have one strike against it.  Certainly, do it if appropriate, but be aware of the consequences.

Comment: "consider the WPF Style property" -- For this reason, I always use lowerCase property names: for example, I might have a property named "style" whose type is "Style". I'm aware though that this doesn't match the MS-recommended standard naming conventions for C#.

Comment: @Vince One hypothesis is that the C# language designers used the "don't knock yourself out and make your compiler bloated by second-guessing the worst-case idiot end-user" principle, and did not create elaborate mechanisms to guard from worst-case coding practice. imho it is an intolerably poor programming practice to have ambiguous names in your code except, perhaps, as the result of running an obfuscator to make it unreadable. best,

Answer (score 8):

> is there any reason why a return type of a property can have the same name as the property?

You are designing a programming language. Should this be legal?

```
enum Color
{
  Red,
  Blue,
  Mauve
}

class Rectangle
{
    ...
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

You have two choices. (1) Make it illegal. Require anyone who does this to come up with a different name for the type and the property. Perhaps you would care to give some suggestions as to what a good name for the type or the property would be that isn't "Color".  (2) Make it legal.

We have no interest in imposing the burden of option (1) on you.

Allowing the property and its type to have the same name introduces some interesting ambiguities in name resolution, which we call "the Color Color problem".  For some thoughts on this, see my article on one aspect of it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

Or, read the C# specification section on the Color Color problem; there's an interesting explanation of why the lookup rules are as they are.

Answer (score 7):

"int" is a reserved word in C#. Int32 is a declared type. You can have a member named Int32 because the member is scoped to your class whereas the Int32 declared type has a different scope.

Comment: I thought int mapped to the class Int32 and int was just a short hand

Comment: It is, but the compiler recognizes it as a specifically reserved keyword, while Int32 is any other class as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Because `int` is a keyword. You can't have variable or property names that are the same as keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume its because lowercase "int" is a basic type recognized by the compiler while Int32 is a class in the default library.

I could very well be wrong though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the language specifications, this has to do with how compilers work. Most compilers use two passes (grossly simplified):

- Lexing: read text, convert into tokens
- Parsing: arrange tokens into logical nested structures

'int' is known at the lexing stage because it is a language keyword, but 'Int32' is just a name which can stand for either a type or a property.

Example:

```
public Int32 Int32 {get; set;}
```

is converted into something like:

```
<public> <identifier "Int32"> <identifier "Int32"> <lbrace> <get> <set> <rbrace>
```

where <xxx> is a token.

Then parsed into:

```
{declaration attribute<public> type<"Int32"> property<"Int32"> ...}
```

where the set of types and set of names don't conflict. Basically, the compiler is able to determine whether you are referring to a type or a name based on the structure of the statement.

But when you use 'int':

```
public int int {get; set;}
```

into

```
<public> <type-int> <type-int> <lbrace> <get> <set> <rbrace>
```

and you can see how this breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

I do it all of the time.  Maybe not with obvious types such as int, but I would often use a property like this:

```
public Expression Expression { get; set; }
```

It doesn't cause me any problems...C# is a pretty smart about types vs properties and it's not as confusing as it looks.  It becomes difficult to find the variable and type names for some things and therefore it's a nice feature.