# Newbie question about PascalCase

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, pascalcasing

ReSharper extension of VS suggest me to use PascalCase in below property.

```
public Color Color { get; private set; }
```

Here Color is Enum type. I would never thought this can be possible because it is same name with type. But it is valid. Is it something suggested by general rules ? Do I have to listen ReSharper always ? Would be appreciated good reference links for PascalCase.

Comment: There is a Microsoft Framework Design Guideline that says something along the line of, _"Consider giving a property the same name as its type."_ So yes, this is recommended (not for every property, but where it makes sense).

Comment: Note that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095644/giving-a-property-the-same-name-as-its-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746117/why-is-it-possible-to-have-properties-named-the-same-as-their-return-types/1746372#1746372

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called the Color Color problem actually and is explained here;

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915215712/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx)

And yes, it is supposed to work and follows the naming typically agreed upon naming convention rules.  I would leave it as you show it in your example.

Comment: Actually, this code could *introduce* the Color Color problem, but the property itself is perfectly valid because the syntax for properties is always `accessmodifier(s) type Name`

Comment: I get shocked that there is same naming problem with my spesific question.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Yes, I probably could have worded that better, but I think that the OP gets what I was driving at.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting on here makes it particularly confusing, but the compiler know when to expect a type and when to expect a name so its no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is recommended. I suggest that you follow ReSharper guidelines, especially if you are new to programming.

Wikipedia article about [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) has some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

> The following guidelines provide the
>   general rules for identifiers.
>
> Do use Pascal casing for all public
>   member, type, and namespace names
>   consisting of multiple words.

Listen to ReSharper ;)

Comment: Listen to ReSharper for just this spesific question or for everything?

Comment: Just for this specific question.
I do not have enough ReSharper experience, but looks like it is always right.

Comment: You shouldn't blindly listen to anything, and that goes beyond programming.  The OP wanted to know the "why" behind the suggestion, which is a good thing.