# Is it dangerous, or bad practice, to call this string "String"?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a class called `SerializableString` which extends a base class `CustomXmlSerializable`. The base class provides methods for XML serializing and deserializing the derived class.

```
public class SerializableString : CustomXmlSerializable
{
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, I can call the `string` property anything I want. But because this class is so general in nature, it would be nice to give it a very obvious name like "String." This way, the property can be accessed as:

```
SerializableString userName = new SerializableString();
userName.String = "khargoosh";
```

The compiler allows this. Notwithstanding the nature of the class and property, would it be considered bad practice, or dangerous, to give the one and only property in the class the name "String" ?

Comment: I'd say it's always bad practice to give a property a name that is a reserved keyword or a type, even if the compiler allows it. It's just confusing is all.

Comment: P.S. "khargoosh" means "rabbit" in Farsi in case anyone was wondering :)

Comment: This is my feeling as well. But I'd like to learn if (and why) it might be dangerous. +1 for the translation!!!

Comment: In your case, I think "Value" or "Content" would be more acceptable names for your property.

Comment: You *can* write a lot of code, should you is really personal choice. You can `var @var=...;` or `if(@if){...}`, but please do not come back asking question to explain "Foo is namespace but used like class" - read specification yourself and let other suffer because they did not :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov which side of the fence does that comment land you on? (your opinion is valued :-)

Comment: Will I ever need to deal with code like this (i.e. in SO posts) - don't. If you want to make *your* life more interesting - go ahead, just don't make others suffer.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Nonsense.  What about `Color`?

Comment: @Micky Color is neither a keyword nor a common type. It's also a rare case that makes sense. One good example out of a million bad ones doesn't count.

Comment: I agree with @PoweredByOrange here. `String` is a primitive type and this is really part of the foundation of the question.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Maybe there are others?  Maybe rephrase _"it's **always** bad practice"_

Comment: @Micky Fair enough, it's _usually_ a bad practice.

Comment: [Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size(v=vs.110).aspx) then?  [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx)?  I know they are not common types but still. :)

Comment: Not common at all. Whereas String is extremely common and is used all the time, so is "Using", "Var", "Void", "Public", "Private", and things of that nature. I think you are missing my point.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange _"I think you are missing my point"_ - OP is creating a _wrapper_ class for a `string` which will expose a **single** `string` property.  I think most people are missing his.

Comment: @Micky "String" is non-conventional name for such property - "Value" or maybe "Text" would likely be more appropriate (and likely align with other classes OP creates for serialization)... But that is even more opinion based that original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this, even though it's valid as far as the compiler is concerned. Eric Lippert's example of `Color Color` is different - most things rarely have more than one color property so naming a property `Color` usually tells you all you need to know about that property. I call this a valid case where using the type name (`Color`) is fine to be used as the name of the property. (One could argue whether this is a good argument but in the past I had to deal with this exact problem and ended up using `Color Color`.)

In the case of `string String` you don't learn anything from the name of the property - a given object may have (and objects frequently do) several properties of type `string`. Naming a property `String` doesn't tell you anything about the purpose of that property. This makes the code harder to understand.

This is just a personal opinion - as the other answer points out, this is syntactically valid. At the end, this is a judgement call - I'd avoid naming a property after its type as much as possible. Longer, unique property / function names usually carry more information about the intended use of that symbol.

Specifically for this question, I'd call the property `Value`:

```
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't mean to argue, please help me understand your point. This seems to be a semantic argument - how is a `string` called String any different than a `Color` called Color? The only purpose of a `SerializableString` is to be a single String.  The only intended use of this `string` is to be a string.  Shouldn't the functional information be carried in the name of the instance of this class?

Comment: `public void ValidateNameFieldRemainsIntactIfNotProvidedOMGThisMethodNameIsSoLongSomeoneShootMe() { }` :)

Comment: @xxbbcc Just a joke on "Longer, unique property / function names usually carry more information". I saw something similar to that in a code base I worked on a while back :) at any rate, I upvoted your answer because I agree with you.

Comment: @khargoosh You're right, it's a semantic argument. The factual answer to your question is that it's valid to name a function after a type. In most situations it'll cause confusion or hide information that would come from a better name. In other cases, it's fine and finding a "better" name may just backfire.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Ah, ok. :)  Yes, I've seen such names in the past, too - a long name like that is just as bad as variables like `a`, `aa`, `aaa` and `aaaa`. (I've seen these in a 40,000+ line long .asp file in the past.)

Comment: @xxbbcc `value` is also a keyword as you know.

Comment: @khargoosh No, `Value` is not a keyword - `value` is. In a case-sensitive language, those are 2 unrelated symbol names.

Comment: Also, Microsoft uses "Value" as property names all over the place. Take a look at any `Nullable<T>` type.

Comment: @xxbbcc `value` is [Contextual Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx) unlike `if` [Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), and more info - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx

Comment: OP is talking about creating a wrapper class for a single `string` so I don't see the problem when it will expose a single `String` property.  The class is self-explanatory

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes you're right, although in this discussion I don't think it matters much.

Comment: I am selecting this as the answer. Although I don't agree 100% with the reasoning behind the answer ("you don't learn anything from the name of the property" - in this case, there's not much that can be learned, it is meant to be general in nature), I think this is the best answer so far because although the answer points out that it is allowed by the C# spec, and syntactically valid, it seems generally agreed that it is not best practice. No, it doesn't cause a _problem_ to do this, but it is more well agreed that it should be avoided if possible. I used the property name `Value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric Lippert himself says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970322/3832080), this is "perfectly acceptable practice; the C# language has been carefully designed so that this is legal and practical."

Furthermore, in this case it seems unambiguous what your String property means: you have a class which is like a string, but serializable, and this property returns the underlying string. Suppose in fact that `String` was not a primitive type, and the primitive type was `str` or something. Then it does not seem to me that there would be any problem or ambiguity in calling this property (the central property of your class) simply "String" (with return type `str` in my hypothetical case)

Comment: That answer refers to properties being named after their type in general - I doubt he would be so accepting of a property named after a primitive type.

Comment: Is there much distinction in c# between primitive types and others?

Comment: And in fact one of the questions Eric [links to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746117/why-is-it-possible-to-have-properties-named-the-same-as-their-return-types) concerns an example with a primitive type

Comment: @user3832080 Eric's example uses the type "Color" and a property called "Color" on that type, which makes sense because in this case, the two have the same logical meaning. Although I'd personally call the "Color" property "Value", to be more precise.

Comment: The example is identical, except with the type "Color" there and "String" here, and with Eric not specifying any context or further detail about the property (whereas here we are told about the SerializableString etc)

Comment: @user3832080 Yes, the compiler treats primitive types differently in many ways.  That said - it's obviously not _illegal_ to have a property named `String` and may not cause any _problems_, but I would certainly not call it good practice.  Too many ways for someone reading the code to get confused.

Comment: @DStanley The compiler treating primitive types differently would only be relevant if it led to potential problems in this case (and the language and compiler have been designed specifically so it does not). I do not see how the `String` case is any more or less confusing than the `Color` case